# Functions are getting undefined in a component when component is mounted again. (React+Electron)

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm working on a Desktop application using Electron and React. For communicating between these two, I'm using **contextBridge** approach like this:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'api', {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            let validChannels = [
                'getProjectId',
                'getTaskDetails',
                and so on...
            ]
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data)
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = [
                'taskDetails',
                'projectId',
                and so on...
            ]
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                const subscription = (event, ...args) => func(...args)
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, subscription)
                return () => {
                    console.log('Removing listener: ', channel)
                    ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, subscription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Now, in React, I'm calling this **receive** call inside **useEffect** hook with an empty dependency array. Like below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const projectIdEvent = window.api.receive('projectId', (id) => {
        setProjectId(id)
    })
    console.log('projectIdEvent', projectIdEvent)

    const taskDetailEvent = window.api.receive('taskDetails', (data) => {
        setTaskDetail(data)
        setLoading(false)
    })
    console.log('taskDetailEvent', taskDetailEvent)

    return () => {
        console.log('Cleanup function...')
        projectIdEvent()
        taskDetailEvent()
    }
}, [])
```

When this component is mounted for the first time, all thing are working perfectly, the logs of above is mentioned below:

```
projectIdEvent ƒ () { [native code] }
taskDetailEvent ƒ () { [native code] }
```

If this component is unmounted at any instance, the cleanup code is fired which is also as expected:

```
Cleanup function...
Removing listener:  projectId
Removing listener:  taskDetails
```

But, when this component is mounted again, these **receive** functions are not getting added and fired. Also in added logs, I'm getting undefined:

```
projectIdEvent undefined
taskDetailEvent undefined
```

It is not clear to me why these are not getting added, I confirmed that when this component mounts at the second point **useEffect** is getting called.
Also, if I add any other simple function like *const test = () => console.log('test')* inside **useEffect**, it is adding every time component mounts.
Only these **window.api.receive** functions are not adding and firing.

Answer (score 0):

The varialbe `validChannels` is empty, you should initialize the array:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'api', {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            const validChannels = ["projectId", "taskDetails"]; // <=== Initialize this array
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data)
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            const validChannels = ["projectId", "taskDetails"]; // <=== Initialize this array
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                const subscription = (event, ...args) => func(...args)
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, subscription)
                return () => {
                    console.log('Removing listener: ', channel)
                    ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, subscription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: **validChannels** is already filled with all expected events. Updated the question now.