# window Object getting overwritten using React in Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, window-object

I'm using react in electron trying to receive data from the main process to my renderer using the steps outlined here.  https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { channels } from "../../shared/constants";
const { api } = window;

const ScanRegion = () => {
  const [video, setVideo] = useState({});
  const [displaySources, setDisplaySources] = useState([]);

  console.log("test", api);

  useEffect(() => {
    api.receive(channels.GET_DATA, (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setDisplaySources(data);
    });
  }, [displaySources]);
```

[dev-tools-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keBO6.png)

It seems like my renderer is picking up the function from the preload script's contextBridge, and then for some reason the window object is getting overwritten when react reloads, and I no longer have access to the receive function.

I haven't seen anyone else with this issue so maybe it's a really simple fix, here the rest of the related files.

preload:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
  receive: (channel, func) => {
    ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
  },
});
```

main:

```
function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  win.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");

  win.webContents.openDevTools();
}
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "electron": "^22.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
```

edit: I'm fairly certain [this post has the same issue as me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69753585/functions-are-getting-undefined-in-a-component-when-component-is-mounted-again) but his question was never answered as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide error message as text, not as image